# Same styles to Bootstrap Documentation site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a demo of some sort online study book. I am trying to use bootstrap as a core for my styles but it feels like it's not enough.

What I really like is a bootstrap site itself: [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/).
Both of these sidebars with navigation and this fancy header. Plus they have nicer styles for typography:

[image: Bootstap site layout]

So I have two question:

1) Am I allowed to use their styles?

2) If so what will be the right way to get those styles? I can see two extra files in the head of the site but I hope that maybe there is a repository or something.

P.S. any other advises are welcome too. Maybe you can recommend framework for online books/documentation or something?

Thanks.

**UPD:** For those who vote negatively on this question could you please explain why?

Comment: read grid system of bootstrap thats all u need and there has so many example follow them

Comment: @sayalok as I said it is not enough. There are lots of small details that is not a part of Bootstrap inself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're directly allowed to use their styles. However, you could always legally obtain a similar template such as
https://guidebook.webuildthemes.com/html/docs/layout-2.html

Alternatively, there are plenty of other free options designed to build documentations and have them customized to suit your design needs. A few of them are listed below:

https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/installation

https://docsify.js.org/#/

https://daux.io/

https://www.mkdocs.org/